# Python Port scanning am i doing it right?

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

So i am making a python program with what i learnd so far where the user enters two ips that represents the start and and of the range of ips to be scanned than saves the wanted ip in a text file.
here is what i came up with:

```
   #ip range and scanning
import socket
import sys
ok=[]
def ipscan(start2,port):
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(2)
    try:
        s.connect((start2,port))
        print start2 ,'-->port %s is Open'%port
        ok.append(start2)
    except: print start2 ,'-->port %s is Closed ! '%port
def iprange(start,end):
    while end>start:
       start[3]+=1
       ipscan('.'.join(map(str,start)),p)
       for i in (3,2,1,0):
          if start[i]==255:
             start[i-1]+=1
             start[i]=0
 #--------------------------------------------#    
sta=map(int,raw_input('From : ').split('.'))
fin=map(int,raw_input('to : ').split('.'))
p=input('Port to scan : ')
iprange(sta,fin)
print '-----------end--------------'
of=open('Output.txt','w')
for ip in ok:
    of.writelines(ip+'\n')
of.close()
```

it seems to be working but i need to be sure,and wanted to know if i can make it any faster?or if there is a better way.

Comment: This might be a good question to post or move to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ seeing as how you're looking more for general advice than asking a specific question.

Comment: Doing it this way will slow you down for "filtered" ports, because you'll have to wait for the connection to time out. Generally it's not necessary to establish a connection anyway, just send a SYN packet and see if you get a SYN-ACK, RST, or nothing. This requires raw sockets, however.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `nmap` ;)

Your socket connections are all sequential. You could parallelize the connections, because that is the slow factor, especially for filtered (not responding) ports.